# Quran ayat of sajdah or sujūd during salat

Tags: quran, salat, sajda

We know that there are [fourteen places in the Holy  Quran](http://al-quran.info/page//quran/prostration) ([also mentioned fifteen](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/sajda-of-tilawah-in-quran)) where we need to perform sajdah or sujūd. Whenever we are reciting the Holy Quran, it is obligatory/recommended upon us to immediately perform the sajdah.

Now, during (mostly tarabih) salat we often see the imam announcing  before start that there is a sajdah in the first or second rakat. This is the most common method where we see on extra sajdah in that rakat in addition to the regular two.

Is it permissible for the imam to make a niyat (mental intention) that the regular sajdah will be sufficient for the extra sajdah needed in that rakat? That means the imam recites an ayat of sajdah, *does not* perform any extra sajdah, and when asked later on, explains that he made a niyat (mental intention) that the regular sajdah will be sufficient for the ayat of sajdah.

I hope that I have made my question clear. Please answer with sufficient references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> explains that he made a niyat (mental intention) that the regular sajdah will be sufficient for the ayat of sajdah

Yes, that's permissible. See, for example, [QIBLA.COM: Sajdah Tilawa, Qada Salat](http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=1206&CATE=4):

> If you recite a verse of prostration as the imam or if praying alone, you should prostrate at the end of the verse, come back up, recite a few more verses, and then bow. If the verse of prostration is at the end of the sura, it is nonetheless recommended to add some verses. **However, it is also permitted to simply bow, while intending to make one's regular prayer prostration also count for the verse of prostration. One needs to intend this, and to bow shortly after reciting the verse.**