# is it permitted for Muslim footballers / sportsmen to prostrate after scoring a goal?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sujud

There is a trend with Muslim footballers (or sportsmen) doing the sujood on the pitch after scoring a goal (or whatever they do in their particular sport to win) - is this permitted to do and the correct thing to do for expressing shukr to Allah swt?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help] to make yourself familiar with our site and model. I also suppose that your inquiry is covered here [Can I perform sujud shukr without wudu/ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/can-i-perform-sujud-shukr-without-wudu-ablution)

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, there is a concept of 'Sujood al-Shukr' which means literally Sujood of Thankfulness.

This is a Sahih Hadith from Sunan Abi Dawud:

> When anything came to the Prophet (ﷺ) which caused pleasure (or, by which he was made glad), he prostrated himself in gratitude to Allah.
>
> Arabic, Book 15, Hadith 298

So, it is Sunnah to do Sajdah at a good occasion or anything that makes you happy (that is not a sin), and of course the Quran is full of places telling people to be more thankful, and Sajdah is a way of showing gratitude.

> فَاذْكُرُونِي أَذْكُرْكُمْ وَاشْكُرُوا لِي وَلَا تَكْفُرُونِ - 2:152
>
> So, remember Me, (and) I will remember you; and give thanks to Me; and do not disbelieve Me.
>
> وَلَقَدْ آتَيْنَا لُقْمَانَ الْحِكْمَةَ أَنِ اشْكُرْ لِلَّهِ ۚ وَمَن يَشْكُرْ فَإِنَّمَا يَشْكُرُ لِنَفْسِهِ ۖ وَمَن كَفَرَ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ غَنِيٌّ حَمِيدٌ - 31:12
>
> And indeed We already brought Luqman (the) wisdom, saying, "Give thanks to Allah. And whoever gives thanks (to Allah), then surely he gives thanks only for himself; (i.e., for his own benefit) and whoever disbelieves, then surely Allah is Ever-Affluent, Ever-Praiseworthy."

In conclusion, there is no reason to consider sajdah done as gratitude for goals scored (or for any other good occasion) as anything haram. Rather, it is sunnah and it is something good, as long as it is done with the right intention (to thank Allah).

Comment: Totally agree. The most important part of your answer is the intention. One should do with the intention to thank Allah and to show off in front of people once religiosity.